# Aren't these two definitions of residue class contradicting each other?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, definition

From [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ResidueClass.html)

> The residue classes of a function $f(x)$ mod $n$ are all possible values of the residue $f(x)~(\pmod n)$. For example, the residue classes of $x^2~(\pmod 6)$ are $\{0,1,3,4\}$.

From  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Residue_systems)

> Each residue class modulo $n$ may be represented by any one of its members, although we usually represent each residue class by the smallest nonnegative integer which belongs to that class (since this is the proper remainder which results from division). Any two members of different residue classes modulo $n$ are incongruent modulo $n$. Furthermore, every integer belongs to one and only one residue class modulo $n$.

So, the Wolfram means that the residue class of $f(x)=x~ (\pmod n)$ is $\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$ while Wikipedia says that residue classes are $[0],[1],\dots,[n-1]$ where $[x]=\{x+kn\}$ for integer $k$ and that is contradicting.

Also, the Wikipedia definition is affirmed by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956878/what-is-meant-by-residue-system-and-residue-class-in-modular-arithmetic/1957003?noredirect=1#comment4019635_1957003) post on StackExchange.

Comment: I see no contradiction, just some sloppy notation on both Wolfram and Wikipedia. The function $f(x)=x^2$ has four residue classes modulo $6$ in its image, which make up the set $\{[0],[1],[3],[4]\}$. The set of residue classes of $f(x)=x$ modulo $n$ has $n$ residue classes: $\{[0], [1], ..., [n-1]\}$. Each of the residue classes are as defined in Wikipedia.  Do not confuse _residue system_ with _residue class_.  A residue system is a set of residue classes.

Comment: @qman But Wolfram declares residue class as {$0,1,3,4$} instead of {$[0],[1],[3],[4]$}

Comment: Wolfram says:
"The residue classes of a function $f(x)$ mod $n$ are all possible values of the residue $f(x) \pmod{n}$. For example, the residue classes of $x^2 \pmod{6}$ are $\{0,1,3,4\}$ ..."
They are referring to the four residue classes each represented by an integer that is contained in the class, not to one class with four elements.  Notice that they use the plural, "residue classes", not the singular, which seems to be your interpretation.  I did mention that I consider their notation as being sloppy.